# react push unique objects in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that is supposed to add unique elements to an array:

```
addLanguage = (val) => {

    for(let i=0; i< val.length; i++){
        console.log(val[i].id)
        if(this.state.createNewDeliveryData.languages.indexOf(val[i].id === -1)){
             this.state.createNewDeliveryData.languages.push(val[i])
        }
    }
}
```

the argument 'val' each time gets an array with appended elements (I have a multi select box on UI from where I add languages), that's why in If loop I am trying to check if my languages array already has that specific element. However this has no effect and at the end my languages array contains same elements i.e. same element is added twice or thrice etc. on subsequent calls.

```
['German']
['German', 'German', 'Arabic']
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to check manually by any unique identifier of object is it exist into array or not before push then you can push. 

for this you can use lodash `uniq` or `unionWith`.

Comment: Where's `id` coming from? Looks like an array of strings to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the index of `false` in your array. That's because, `indexOf(val[i].id === -1)` will always check `indexOf(false)` which is -1. So you re-add each language.

You are probably after an algorithm more similar to this:

```
addLanguage = (val) => {
    // Get a copy of the languages state. 
    const languages = [...this.state.createNewDeliveryData.languages];
    for(let i=0; i< val.length; i++){
        if(languages.indexOf(val[i].id) === -1) { // notice that there is a parenthesis after `id`.
            languages.push(val[i].id)
        }
    }
    this.setState({createNewDeliveryData: {languages}}); // update state and trigger re-render if there are new languages. 
}
```

Note that you should always use `setState` to mutate the state in react.

Comment: Isn't that the correct way to check for element existence before pushing to array?

Comment: No. In your code you litterally do if(array.indexOf(false)===-1. when you don't want to store booleans in your array

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking each element in a loop, you could just use `Set` object to remove every duplicated element.

*Note*: I assume that the `val` variable is an array.

```
addLanguage = (val) => [...new Set(val)];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues with your code:

- First of all, **never, ever** mutate `this.state` directly. It is anti-pattern 
  and may yield undesired results. Use `this.setState()` instead.
- There is no need to do `indexOf` in a loop. `indexOf` will iterate the array and return the index of the searched item, or `-1` if it was not in the array.
- You have to create a copy for the `this.state.createNewDeliveryData` object *and* for the `languages` array.

---

That said, one solution could be:

```
addLanguage = (val) => {
  if(this.state.createNewDeliveryData.languages.indexOf(val) === -1) {
    let obj = Object.assign({}, this.state.createNewDeliveryData);  //shallow-copy object
    let arr = obj.languages.slice();  //copy array
    arr.push(val);  //push the value
    obj.languages = arr;  //assign the new array to our copied object
    this.setState({createNewDeliveryData: obj});  //replace the old object with the new
  }
}
```

or in a more compact form:

```
addLanguage = (val) => {
  if(this.state.createNewDeliveryData.languages.indexOf(val) === -1) {
    let obj = Object.assign({}, this.state.createNewDeliveryData);  //shallow-copy object
    obj.languages = obj.languages.slice().push(val);
    this.setState({createNewDeliveryData: obj});  //replace the old object with the new
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks! I actually do not want to push 'val' as it is, that's why I was iterating over the val array and using val[i].id to push into my languages array.

Comment: Also, if I put a console.log(this.state.createNewDeliveryData.languages) outside if loop, it prints empty array each time

Comment: @Nitish, yes my bad. It should be `=== -1`, not `> -1`. Corrected the error.

Comment: this latest update is throwing : Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `array` supplied to `Value`, expected `object`

Comment: @Nitish, that seems unrelated to this issue. That means that you are sending a prop called `value` which is an array down to `<Value>`, when it should be an object.

Comment: Okay! Answer from Christopher worked, so I accepted it. Sorry I can not accept two answers but I have given +1. Thanks a lot anyway :)